# How do I provide Google Analytics my operating system?

Tags: c#, google-analytics

I'm writing an application in c#. I have integrated Google Analytics using the [Analytics measurement protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/) using HttpWebRequest.

The problem is, when viewing the analytics, the operating system is always listed as

> (not set)

The only concession to setting the OS in the reference docs that I can find would be [setting the user agent](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#ua) - but I don't know how to format that considering this is a desktop application, not a web browser.

Comment: It does not seem to be able to isolate desktop web browser and desktop app.

Answer (score 2):

At least as of the time of this writing https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-analytics-measurement-protocol/5S4xEAxd1_o/ed9PJrOzd_UJ, you are not able to set the OS as it's

> set through a user-agent mapping.

The post goes on to suggest sending that info in through a custom dimension.